# Retrieve html5.js using https when using a secure connection

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl

The page `https://stackexchange.com` (kudos for SSL) works flawlessly on all browsers except IE, which says

> Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security ceritifcate errors.

I think this is due to the lines

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

which is easily fixable since `https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js` leads to the same file.

I know that SSL is not a priority right now, but once I saw it, I couldn't un-see it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed now.

Bear in mind that SSL-enabling stackexchange.com is a work in progress – for example, the homepage still serves some content over http.

Right now, SSL is just used for the [OAuth 2.0 flow in API v2](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) (which uses html5.js in IE, which is why this was a valid bug).